# Pandas GroupedBy Dataframe sorting by values of column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

My question is about sorting. I've read here multiple questions about groupby dataframes sorting but none of them solved my problem or maybe I'm doing something wrong because I get different errors like *bool not callable* or *sort_values not available* or stuff like that.

I got a dataframe with some info and columns. Then I created a groupby dataframe properly, based on 2 fields.

Then I do this:

```
for name, group in mydfgrouped:
    print(name, len(group))
```

The output I get is this:

```
('A', 'HH') 414
('A', 'LW') 1413
('A', 'ME') 1458
('A', 'MR') 339
('B', 'HH') 126
('B', 'LW') 288
('B', 'ME') 315
('B', 'MR') 54
('C', 'HH') 879
('C', 'LW') 672
('C', 'ME') 984
('C', 'MR') 186
('D', 'HH') 246
('D', 'LW') 756
('D', 'ME') 795
('D', 'MR') 255
```

I would like to sort this dataframe based on 2 criteria:

1. len of group `HH` **descending** order
2. Name **ascending** order (this is just in case there's a tie in 'HH')

So the idea is to show the same list but descending sorted depending on the value of `HH`, but showing all stats for that name.

My expected output is:

```
('C', 'HH') 879
('C', 'LW') 672
('C', 'ME') 984
('C', 'MR') 186
('A', 'HH') 414
('A', 'LW') 1413
('A', 'ME') 1458
('A', 'MR') 339
('D', 'HH') 246
('D', 'LW') 756
('D', 'ME') 795
('D', 'MR') 255
('B', 'HH') 126
('B', 'LW') 288
('B', 'ME') 315
('B', 'MR') 54
```

As you can see, name `C` is first because it got the highest len in group `HH` (879). And I want to get all groups from `C`. The last one is `B` because it got the lowest len of group `HH` (126)

sort_values and sort did not work for me

Comment: Could you include a small section of data, please? We don't need 16 lines -- five or so should be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the second column that you're grouping by is called `y`, you can do:

```
# mydfgrouped = df.groupby(['x', 'y'])

s = mydfgrouped.size().unstack('y').sort_values('HH', ascending=False).stack()

for (i, l) in s.items():
    print(i, l)
```

Output:

```
('C', 'HH') 879
('C', 'LW') 672
('C', 'ME') 984
('C', 'MR') 186
('A', 'HH') 414
('A', 'LW') 1413
('A', 'ME') 1458
('A', 'MR') 339
('D', 'HH') 246
('D', 'LW') 756
('D', 'ME') 795
('D', 'MR') 255
('B', 'HH') 126
('B', 'LW') 288
('B', 'ME') 315
('B', 'MR') 54
```

Brief explanation:

```
# unstack `y` into columns
mydfgrouped.size().unstack('y')

# y   HH    LW    ME   MR
# x                      
# A  414  1413  1458  339
# B  126   288   315   54
# C  879   672   984  186
# D  246   756   795  255

# sort by HH
mydfgrouped.size().unstack('y').sort_values('HH', ascending=False)

# y   HH    LW    ME   MR
# x                      
# C  879   672   984  186
# A  414  1413  1458  339
# D  246   756   795  255
# B  126   288   315   54

# stack `y` back into rows
mydfgrouped.size().unstack('y').sort_values('HH', ascending=False).stack()
```

Comment: thanks, this is what i was looking for. Now i need to learn about this size, stack and new stuff. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes, exactly! I've added a brief explanation of what's going on there, hope it helps make it a bit less mysterious )